# Union tables by field name? (i.e. columns order cannot be guaranteed)

Tags: sql, union, field

I'd like to stack tables via UNION, but do it by field name, as the tables have mostly the same fields, but each table may not have all the fields, and the column order may differ.  E.g.

```
Table 1     Table 2     Table 3     Table 4
Age         Age          Age        Height
Height      Height       Height     Weight
Weight      Weight       Weight     Age
Race        Race         Gender     Gender
---         Gender
```

For instance, the following code may break in the example below:

```
      SELECT * FROM TABLE 1 
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM TABLE 2
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM TABLE 3
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM TABLE 4
```

The motivating example is surveys with quarterly or annual waves. Sometimes fields get dropped and others added each year.  I'd like to set up a process now that won't require excessive attention to mapping out past changes or break as a result of minor future changes.

Languages like SAS will handle that gracefully matching columns by name. Is there a way to do that concisely in SQL, like "UNION ALL BY NAME" or something?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: In this case Vertica, which supports ANSI SQL and some extensions

Comment: So sorry!  I saw my poor formatting and edited simultaneously.  Newbie to posting to this site

Comment: I rolled it back.  Probably better to leave it where it's at.  If I got something wrong let me know.  Give this a read to get a better understanding of how to format code on SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: No worries.  Once you get the hang of it this site will be your best friend!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One part of the SQL standard BNF grammar includes:

```
<non-join query expression>    ::=
   <non-join query term>
 | <query expression body> UNION  [ALL|DISTINCT] [ <corresponding spec> ] <query term>
 | <query expression body> EXCEPT [ALL|DISTINCT] [ <corresponding spec> ] <query term> 
<corresponding spec>           ::= CORRESPONDING
                         [ BY <left paren> <corresponding column list> <right paren> ]
<corresponding column list>    ::=   <column name list> 
<column name list>    ::=   <column name> [ { <comma> <column name> }... ]
```

So, in theory, you can use a CORRESPONDING clause to achieve exactly the effect you require.  However, not all DBMS support the notation - you will need to read your manual to find out.

If the CORRESPONDING notation is not available, then you will have to list the column names in the correct sequence in each separate part of the UNION query.

Comment: +1  IIUC, the OP will still need to "pad" tables that are missing fields -- like Table 1 is missing "Gender" -- with dummy columns.  At least, that's how it works on the only RDBMS supporting CORRESPONDING BY that I could find on short notice (HSQL 2.0).

Comment: Folks, these answers are very helpful, thank you so much. So probably use an external language to inspect the schema is the most reliable way to go.  The CORRESPONDING BY is a major learning too.   ` LET $fieldnames :=  SELECT DISTINCT fieldName
       FROM (SELECT fieldname FROM table_info WHERE table = "table1") UNION (SELECT fieldname FROM table_info WHERE table = "table2") ...`

    `CREATE TABLE newTable as SELECT ($FIELDNAMES from table1) UNION ALL (SELECT $FIELDNAMES from table2) ...`

Answer (score 4):

I believe that all that is required to UNION all the tables together is that they have the same number of columns with similar data types

So I guess you could do

```
SELECT age, height, weight, gender, race FROM TABLE 1 
UNION ALL SELECT age, height, weight, gender, race FROM TABLE 2
UNION ALL SELECT age, height, weight, gender, race FROM TABLE 3
UNION ALL SELECT age, height, weight, gender, race FROM TABLE 4
```

And if for instance that table 3 did not have the race field you could replace it with.

```
SELECT age, height, weight, gender, null AS race FROM TABLE 3
```

Or another default value instead of null.

Comment: +1  This big SELECT/UNION could be generated automatically, too, by some interface that can inspect the schema (e.g., perl-DBD-Vt) and determine which tables are missing which columns.

Comment: -1 Answering tangentially to the question = didn't really comprehend. It looks like the asker knows this part, but is looking for a solution to auto-magically generate/run the statement using fields across all tables past present and future.